# where can i download these icon theme

Tags: 14.04, icons, icon-themes

I am using 14.04 desktop, on web these tablet icon theme sets are showing off again and again.
but anyone knows how can i get them in use ?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This themes can be downloaded from universe repositories for Ubuntu 14.04.

Open Terminal and Type Following Commands:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mobile-icons
sudo apt-get install suru-icon-theme
```

You can set it from `unity-tweak-tool` (can be downloaded by `apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`)

[image]

To set themes by terminal, **type following commands with your theme name**:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "theme-name"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "theme-name"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "theme-name"
```

Comment: but these are not exactly same...
do you have any screenshot of yours ?

Comment: @RohitKaradkar Have you tried this? Is suru-icon-theme not that you want?

Comment: There's probably something wrong with my desktop, everything got messed up when i set that theme. Thanks for ur support

Answer (score 1):

This is the Suru Icon Theme Package.  Ubuntu’s New Mobile And Desktop Icon Theme, can be downloaded from [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome/suru-icon-theme)

You can use synaptic to download and install packages.  `sudo apt-get install synaptic` or, download the file, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the download location, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

Comment: how should i install those from there ?

Comment: Look at the addition in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Suru theme packs can be found at the Ubuntu-Themes section of Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-themes

Specifically 17.04: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-themes_16.10+17.04.20161205.orig.tar.gz

Specifically 14.04 - 16.10: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-themes_14.04+16.04.20160415.orig.tar.gz

You'll need to drop them into the /usr/share/theme and /icons folders along with any dependent themes (Suru uses Humanity, Ubuntu-mobile and Gnome theming/icons as fallbacks).

Another alternative is to use these icons from Github: https://github.com/clessley/suru-icons-16.10-for-android